# VSTO Starting EXCEL in code ADDIN NOT LOADED

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in, office-interop

I'm launching Excel from code using this code :

```
var excelApp = new MSExcel.Application { Visible = true };
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
excelApp = null;
```

I've added the second line because without it the Excel automatically closes when the launcher closes. When I add new workbook it keeps alive. Howewer, my add-in that has nothing to do with the launcher won;t load. Any suggestions ?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you are trying to do here? I assume this code is not in an add-in, what is running this code?

Comment: Im running excel from console app using the code above. Excel never loads Any addins when it is initialized like this.

Comment: A workaround: If you don't need your console app to interact with Excel, then start the Excel app using `Process.Start()`. This is the same as opening the app from the Start menu, thus all add-ins will load automatically.

Comment: is the addin getting disabled? can you load addin manually or do you have multiple version of excel installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idealy mustnot happen, but a workaround you may try

```
foreach (COMAddIn addin in application.COMAddIns)
{
      if (addin.Description.ToLower().Equals(addinName.ToLower()) || string.Equals(addin.Description, "[AddInName]", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
            addIn.Connect = true;
            break;
         }
}
```